# How does "&" work in comparing two type of data in this code?

Tags: python

I am reading Python Cookbook: "1.17. Extracting a Subset of a Dictionary". I got confused with the "&" usage in one piece of the below code example. Who may help elaborate on it a bit?

How does `prices.keys() & tech_names` work here?

```
prices = {
    'ACME': 45.23,
    'AAPL': 612.78,
    'IBM': 205.55,
    'HPQ': 37.20,
    'FB': 10.75
}
tech_names = {'AAPL', 'IBM', 'HPQ', 'MSFT'}
p2 = {key: prices[key] for key in prices.keys() & tech_names}
```

Comment: @PaulH I disagree, it creates a dict where the key is found in both `prices` and `tech_names` - exactly how I would read the code. `prices.keys() & tech_names` returns `{'AAPL', 'HPQ', 'IBM'}` , again exactly as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&` operator is used to create the *intersection* of the sets of keys in `prices` and the values in `tech_names`.

See the section on [*Dictionary view objects*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects):

> Keys views are set-like since their entries are unique and hashable. *[...]*  For set-like views, all of the operations defined for the abstract base class [`collections.abc.Set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Set) are available (for example, `==`, `<`, or `^`).

Also see the [intersection methods section for `set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection):

> ```
>  set & other & ...
> ```
>
> Return a new set with elements common to the set and all others.

So, the code only defines the prices for the symbols listed in the `tech_names` set.

Another way of spelling this would be to use a `if` filter in the dictionary comprehension; this has the advantage that you can then use `prices.items()` and access the symbol and the price at the same time:

```
p2 = {symbol: price for symbol, price in prices.values() if symbol in tech_names}
```

Comment: @Martijin, thank you for your prompt response and pointing me to the right place. I now realized that keys view are set like data and "&" can be a set operator (I only thought it's a bit operator)

Comment: @XiaokuanWei: In Python, most operators can be overloaded. Sets implement (among other things) the [`__and__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__and__) to provide an intersection result instead.